# Get content after submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i had this script auto login after submit the link will change and i want to download the next page automatic what i should add after the last line 
here is my code

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('localhost/test/login.php');
echo $homepage;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("input[name=email]").val("test@test.com");
    $("input[name=password]").val("test");
    $('#signin-form').submit();
  });
</script>
```

this script is in another file named `auto.php` . so when i run it's work but after the submit the link `localhost/login.php` will redirect to `localhost/index.php` so what i should add to `auto.php` after submit to get the content of l`ocalhost/index.php`
thank you

Comment: You haven't closed `$(function()` and should do redirect in your php . Using `file_get_contents` doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: yeah i forget to closed . after auto submit that will redirect to the index i want to get  the content of the index and put it in text file  that what i need. i use file get content cause the page is another directory

Comment: Not following what your specific problem or errors are here. Not enough problem statement details

Comment: Why `file_get_contents()`? Have you tried `include()`?

Comment: *«i want to download the next page automatic»* == Unclear.

Comment: Sir my problem is after submit that will redirect to another link automatic i want to get content of the new link  and saved in text file that's all .

Comment: Mr . Louys patrice after redirect i want to get content of the page and put it in text file

Comment: This is a form submission. `$_POST` and `$_GET` won't help you to get data from another page?

Comment: Still unclear... *«after redirect»* You mean "after submit", I suppose. We just can't see how you submit what and where. Please edit your question in order to make it a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the exact issue you have (errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), steps to reproduce the issue and what you tried to solve.) -- I voted to close as unclear

Comment: i think you understand that this script in the same page of `login.php` that is problem

Comment: You obviously are not at ease with English... I recommand you look for a friend who would help you edit your question. *«If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.»* -> [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i think you understand that this script in the same page of `login.php` that is problem but let me more explain . this script is in another file named `auto.php` . so when i run it's work but after the submit the link `localhost/login.php` will redirect to `localhost/index.php`  so what i should add to `auto.php` after submit to get the content of `localhost/index.php` i'm sorry sir

Comment: There is an EDIT link below your question... That is intended to add details or modify the question. Use it please. The last comment should be part of the question. --- Additionnaly do you know about the [Spanish StackOverflow site](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)? -- I assume a lot here, because of the "Escobar" in your user name! (no offence) That may be easier for your to post your question there...

Comment: yeah i add the last more details . no sir i'm not spanish it's just name i like it and i'm sorry i hope that last comment explained more details about the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184115/discussion-between-ayoubich-escobar-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of details, I will explain a solution (what I've got from your question).

**Imagine** you have a form in the `auto.php` page that will send some data to `index.php`. You asked for an approach to retrieve data/results from `index.php` without redirecting or something alike. This is a way you can do it by `ajax`:

```
$('#signin-form').on('click', function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    var email= $("input[name=email]").val();
    var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'the_email='+ email +'the_pass'+ password ,
            success: function(respond){
                $('#results').html(respond);
            }
        });
});
```

In `index.php` use `$_POST['the_email']` for email and `$_POST['the_pass']` for password. Use them, manipulate them or whatever you want, and then `echo` the results in `index.php`.

**Please note**: in order to show the results, you have to add new div with `#results` id in `auto.php`. Like below:

`<div id="results"></div>`

Now all data from `index.php` will be shown in `auto.php` without redirecting.